# typescript useRef type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-kirch-21994p?file=/src/App.tsx

```
  const playRef = useRef(null);


  const playOrPause = () => {
  setIsPlaying((prev) => {
  if (playRef) {
    playRef.current[prev ? "pause" : "play"]();
  }
  return !prev;
  });
  };
```

can someone please help me fix this type error

```
  React.MutableRefObject<null>.current: null
   Object is possibly 'null'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the specific type:

Try this:

```
  const playRef = useRef<ImageGallery>(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the if condition and add the type on the useRef like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const playRef = useRef<ImageGallery>(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const playOrPause = () => {
    setIsPlaying((prev) => {
      if (playRef.current !== null) {
        playRef.current[prev ? "pause" : "play"]();
      }
      return !prev;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ImageGallery ref={playRef} items={images} showPlayButton={false} />
      <button onClick={playOrPause}>{isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```